# Spring Boot Repository working with optional Properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, repository

I try to find out "if there is any entity with the given properties".

Given is the following sample entity:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id
    private Long someId;
    @Column
    private String propA;
    @Column
    private String propB;
    @Column
    private String propC;
}
```

I try to find an entity with a given propA. Or propB. Or C. Or a combination of them. I know, I can do this with a JpaRepository, but I will get an exploding number of functions to write:

```
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {

    boolean existsByPropA(String propA);
    boolean existsByPropB(String propB);
    boolean existsByPropC(String propC);
    boolean existsByPropAAndAndPropB(String propA, String propB);
    boolean existsByPropAAndPropC(String propA, String propC);
    // and much more to be written to get all combinations
}
```

Writing all possible combination is nonsense especially if new properties are to be added.

I am looking for a generic solution to this problem, or at least a keyword to search for as I am not yet very firm with JPA/Hibernate.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple way, you can just use a query like this :

```
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Task  as t WHERE EXISTS (SELECT t.title FROM t WHERE t.title=:a or t.title=:b or t.title=:c or(t.title=:a and t.title=:b))")
    Boolean check(String a,String b,String c);
```

but I think the best way is to use specifications

Comment: That's close to what I just found myself in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-null-parameters) and will accept it as answer, thanks.
`@Query("SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE (:name is null or c.name = :name) and (:email is null" + " or c.email = :email)")`
`List<Customer> findCustomerByNameAndEmail(@Param("name") String name, @Param("email") String email);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Criteria Queries](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl), with criteria you are able to create logic for the generation of queries.